# Android app link not working and not appearing in adb dumpsys

Tags: android, reactjs, hyperlink, applinks, android-app-links

I'm trying to set up android app link for my add but they are not working.
I modified my manifest.xaml (android/app/src/main), by adding :

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="example.com" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
  </intent-filter>
```

and added a assetlinks.json to my website (./well-known/assetlinks.json).
And when i validate it by browsing on https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site=https://example.com&relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls, it says there is no errors but my app link is not working when i open it with `adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://example.com"`
When i try to find the app link with `adb shell dumpsys package domain-preferred-apps`, it says it does not exists.
I aldready verified my sha256 key and my app package on the assetlinks.json...
Can someone please help me :)